# Django paginator does not pass second GET

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

My goal is to filter objects by buttons and then parse it to pages. It works but when i go to next page the filter i get from GET just disapears. it works on the first page just fine but when i move to 2.page that is where it doesn't filter.

My view:

```
def Archive(request):
    filte = request.GET.get("category")
    manga = Manga.objects.all()
    if filte != None:
        manga = manga.filter(manga_categorys=filte)

    cats = Categorys.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(manga, 20)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    manlen = len(manga)

    context = {
        "Category": cats,
        "Manga": page_obj,
        "MangaLen":manlen,
    }

    template = loader.get_template("Category.html")

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

And my template(filter):

```
    <form method="GET">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-10 gap-6">
            {%for x in Category%}
                <button class="bgl text-center p-4" type="submit" value="{{x.id}}" name="category"><h2 class="M text-xl ">{{x.category_name}}</h2></button>
            {%endfor%}
        </div>
    </form>
```

Edit : I have also tried:

```
    {%for x in Category%}
        <a class="bgl text-center p-4" href="?category={{x.id}}"><h2 class="M text-xl ">{{x.category_name}}</h2></a>
    {%endfor%}
```

My paginator(they are in the same template):

```
    <div class="pagination mx-auto p-2 flex w-max mt-4 bgl roulnded-lg">
        <span class="step-links">
            {% if Manga.has_previous %}
                <a href="?page=1"> <div class="p-3 text-lg M w-max mx-auto  inline mx-2 border-r-2">&laquo;</div></a>
                <a href="?page={{ Manga.previous_page_number }}"><div class="p-3 text-lg M w-max mx-auto inline mx-2 border-r-2">Önceki</div></a>
            {% endif %}
    
            <span class="current text-lg   p-3 mx-2">
                {{ Manga.number }}
            </span>
    
            {% if Manga.has_next %}
                <a href="?page={{ Manga.next_page_number }}"><div class="p-3 text-lg M w-max mx-auto  inline mx-2 border-l-2">Sonraki</div></a>
                <a href="?page={{ Manga.paginator.num_pages }}"><div class="p-3 text-lg M  w-max mx-auto inline mx-2 border-l-2">&raquo;</div> </a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
```

These are my template and views. As i have said before i dont think i can have 2 get at the same time ? Is there a way around ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your views and template form look fine for the pagination. What you can do is you can include the `category` parameter with the `page` parameter in the pagination links. To do this you can update your template pagination part with the code provided below:

```
<div class="pagination mx-auto p-2 flex w-max mt-4 bgl roulnded-lg">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if Manga.has_previous %}
            <a href="?category={{ request.GET.category|default:'' }}&page=1"> <div class="p-3 text-lg M w-max mx-auto  inline mx-2 border-r-2">&laquo;</div></a>
            <a href="?category={{ request.GET.category|default:'' }}&page={{ Manga.previous_page_number }}"><div class="p-3 text-lg M w-max mx-auto inline mx-2 border-r-2">Önceki</div></a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current text-lg   p-3 mx-2">
            {{ Manga.number }}
        </span>

        {% if Manga.has_next %}
            <a href="?category={{ request.GET.category|default:'' }}&page={{ Manga.next_page_number }}"><div class="p-3 text-lg M w-max mx-auto  inline mx-2 border-l-2">Sonraki</div></a>
            <a href="?category={{ request.GET.category|default:'' }}&page={{ Manga.paginator.num_pages }}"><div class="p-3 text-lg M  w-max mx-auto inline mx-2 border-l-2">&raquo;</div> </a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Here, I have added `{{ request.GET.category|default:'' }}` in the anchor tag href attribute link with a default empty string this empty string will make sure incase no category found and avoid any broken links.